# построить линейный список из символов.Удалить повторяющиеся пробелы

Tags: c#

дан текстовый файл, в котором записана строка символов.Например char.txt с содержимым  "*    %     ; ()    ^" должно получиться "* % ; () ^"
Так же нужно, что бы данный алгоритм работал, если в конце char.txt поставить пробелы
Проблема в удалении повторяющихся пробелов ***

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string path= @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\char.txt";//подключаем этот текстовый файл
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

    List<char> chars = new List<char>();//создаем список
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();//считываем весь текстовый файл и храним в строках

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) { 
      chars.Add(s[i]);//заполняем этот список
      Console.Write(chars[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Count; i++) { //не правильное условие ***
      if (chars[i] == ' ' && chars[i+1] == ' ') {
        i++;
        chars.RemoveAt(i);
      }

      Console.Write(chars[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Проблема то в чем?

Comment: не правильно удаляет пробелы.Должен быть один пробел,а тут и два и три

Comment: Итерироваться по коллекции, которую изменяешь, так себе идея. Заведи пустой List<char> copy, и если последний элемент copy не пробел или chars[i] не пробел, добавляй chars[i] в конец copy.

Comment: а можно trim'ом  сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`Regex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) и [`Replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
string testData = "*    %     ; ()   ^";
Regex removeSpaces = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
testData = removeSpaces.Replace(testData, " ");

Console.WriteLine(testData);
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/Z28LyM): `* % ; () ^`

> Q: Чем хорош такой подход?
>
> A: Тем, что не будут затронуты пробелы стоящие по 1му, будут затронуты
>   только те, места, в которых будет более одного пробела.

Answer (score 1):

Для строки в которую записываете текст из файла используйте метод `str.Trim()` (где str - ваша строка), он обрежет пробелы в начале и конце. А для удаления лишних пробелов используйте метод `str.Replace("  ", " ")`, нужно заменить все места с двумя пробелами на один пробел. Так у вас останется только по одному пробелу.

Пример кода:

```c#
string str;   //ваша строка
/*запись строки*/
str.Trim();    //обрезаем в начеле и конце
str.Replace("  ", " ");    //заменяем
```

Answer (score 0):

Все работает спасибо.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string path= @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\react\c#\char.txt";//подключаем этот файл
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

    List<char> chars = new List<char>();//создаем список
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();//считываем весь текстовый файл и храним в строках

    Regex removeSpaces = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
    s = removeSpaces.Replace(s, " ");

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) { 
      chars.Add(s[i]);//заполняем этот список
      Console.Write(chars[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам цикл? Вызовите метод [`ToCharArray()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.7.2). У результата строки.